supervisor error: The directory named as part of the path /not/real/path/ does not exist in section 'program:TextAlertServer'
This is my first time using supervisor. In my supervisord.conf file I have a path for stdout_logfile that matches the error, so I don't understand why it gives me the error:

Error: The directory named as part of the path
/usr/local/var/log/supervisor/TextAlertServer-stdout.log does not
exist in section 'program:TextAlertServer' (file:
'/usr/local/etc/supervisord.conf')

This is what I have in my supervisord.conf file for my program:
[program:TextAlertServer]
command=sudo swift run App serve --port=8080
directory=/var/www/TextAlertServer
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=Andrew
stdout_logfile=/usr/local/var/log/supervisor/TextAlertServer-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/usr/local/var/log/supervisor/TextAlertServer-stderr.log

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I created the directory and now we're good to go.
